# Why, if principal ideals are different, they are not 2-sided?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

There is an argument about ring ideals which I do not understand.

> Let $R$ be a ring with $1$,
>   $$a=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},$$ $I=\{a\}\cdot M_2(R)$,
>   $J=M_2(R)\cdot\{a\}$. $I$ is a right ideal and $J$ is a left ideal of
>   $M_2(R)$. Observe that, if $R$ is not trivial, $I\not=J$ and hence
>   none of them is 2-sided.

I do not understand this “hence”. How is $I\not=J$ relevant? I can prove that $J$ is not a right ideal in a concrete way: the right column of every member of $J$ is zero and $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

I guess I need to prove something like “if $J=S\cdot\{a\} $ is a right ideal, then $J=\{a\}\cdot S $” for an abstract ring $S$ with $1$. I proved the following. $1\in S$, $1\cdot a\in J $, $a\in J $. [Let $s\in S$ be given. $a\cdot s\in J $ because $J$ is a right ideal.] Hence $\{a\}\cdot S\subseteq J $. What next?

[Update 2017-09-12 19:48:28+03:00. It seems that this is a mistake in the textbook. I publish the parameters of the textbook so the authors can fix it.

Menini, Claudia, and Freddy Van Oystaeyen. *Abstract Algebra: A Comprehensive Treatment.* Marcel Dekker, 2004.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to be uneasy about the wording: it is not completely correct.

It seems to be saying "for a ring $S$, if $xS\neq Sx$, then $xS$ and $Sx$ are both not two-sided ideals." However, there exist examples of rings such that $xS$ is a two-sided ideal, and yet $Sx$ is not, and in such a case, $xS\neq Sx$.

Here is a concrete example ([entry at DaRT](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/38/)). Take any field endomorphism $\sigma:F\to F$ such that $[F:\sigma(F)]>1$. Take the twisted polynomial ring $F[x;\sigma]$ where $x\lambda:=\sigma(\lambda)x$ for each $\lambda \in F$, and let $R$ be the quotient ring $F[x;\sigma]/(x^2)$.  Then $xF[x;\sigma]=xF=\sigma(F)x$ is a principal right ideal which is not a principal left ideal, and $F[x;\sigma]x=Fx$ is a two-sided principal ideal.

What we can say is that if $x\in S$, then $xS$ would be an ideal iff $Sx\subseteq xS$. Similarly, $Sx$ would be an ideal iff $xS\subseteq Sx$.

In the example given, it would be better to say that you can show that neither $aS$ nor $Sa$ are two-sided ideals, because *neither one contains the other one.*

Comment: I am confused: how are $S$ and $R$ related in the last 2 paragraphs?

Comment: @beroal I used $S$ since that appears to be what you were using in your example above. I was worried about using $R$ to refer to your example because you used that as the notation for your base ring. Ah, and yes I see a typo in one of my paragraphs. Maybe I should just switch them all to $S$.

Comment: @beroal Switched them all to $S$ to avoid confusion with the $R$ in your post, and to line up with the $S$ in your post (which apparently denotes the matrix ring, in your case.) Look good?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not understand your counterexample though, I am not that advanced. I appreciate the last 2 paragraphs.

Comment: @beroal The counterexample isn't as hard as it might first seem. Let me know if I can answer any questions about it. For concreteness, you could take $F=K(X)$ for a field $F$, and then the endomorphism that takes $X\mapsto X^2$ gives you a suitable $\sigma$.